# Create shadow of building in ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, 3d-analyst, arcscene, shadow

I want to create shadow of a building at different time in ArcScene but I am a beginner of using ArcScene so I am not familiar with this. I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 version.

I tried to use "sun shadow volume tool" in "visibility" in "3D analyst tool" but the shadow cannot present in different time and in animation.

After that, I found some reference on the internet, it is using "Skyline" and "Skyline barrier" tool to create shadow of the building.
However, I am not understand how to define the position of the Sun and also how to create an animation to present the shadow in different time. Or can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To make an animation of a changing shadow, you should go into the [Scene Properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000900000006000000) and change the Sun Azimuth

> Sets the angular direction of the illumination source used in
>   rendering the scene for each keyframe. The default is 315 degrees
>   (northwest).

and Sun Inclination

> Sets the altitude (the angle of the illumination source above the
>   horizon) used in rendering the scene. The default is 30 degrees above
>   the horizon.

values on the Illumination tab. These can be [varied at each key frame](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/About_animating_scene_properties/000900000017000000/) when [creating a scene based animation](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//000900000064000000).

Comment: It's a good idea to include some context or links to supporting documentation in answers. As it originally appeared, there wasn't much explanation of the properties you mention and where to find them for someone not already familiar with them.